# Reading BitBucket files via Databricks notebook using python

Tags: python, bitbucket, databricks

I am new to Databricks and want to clone Bitbucket repo to Databricks and access the respective files.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried, and where did that fail?  Databricks has documentation on how to pull from version control

Comment: have you tried https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html ?